# Looping multiple values into dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

I would like to expand on a previously asked question:

[Nested For Loop with Unequal Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578130/nested-for-loop-with-unequal-entities)

In that question, I requested a method to extract the location's type (Hospital, Urgent Care, etc) in addition to the location's name (WELLSTAR ATLANTA MEDICAL CENTER, WELLSTAR ATLANTA MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH, etc).

The answer suggested utilizing a for loop and dictionary to collect the values and keys.  The code snippet appears below:

```
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.wellstar.org/locations/pages/default.aspx"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

d = {}
for row in soup.select(".WS_Content > .WS_LeftContent > table > tr"):
title = row.h3.get_text(strip=True)
d[title] = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in row.select(".PurpleBackgroundHeading a)]

pprint(d)
```

I would like to extend the existing solution to include the entity's address matched with the appropriate key-value combination.  If the best solution is to utilize something other than a dictionary, I'm open to that suggestion as well.

Comment: Though related to a previous question, [do make this one a proper question as well](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a dict `my_dict` and you want to add `2` with `my_key` as key. Simply do:

```
my_dict['my_key'] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a dict `d = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7}` now you want to add another value

> 'Sex'= 'female'

You can use built in update method.

```
d.update({'Sex': 'female' })
print "Value : %s" %  d

Value : {'Age': 7, 'Name': 'Zara', 'Sex': 'female'}
```

ref is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm